# MYSQL SUM qty with Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

i have a problem with my SQL query. When I use more then one JOIN, the result is wrong.

```
SELECT name, stock,SUM(order_items.qty),
SUM(shipping_items.qty) FROM shipping_items

JOIN mnm_products 
ON mnm_products.id = shipping_items.product_id

JOIN order_items
ON mnm_products.id = order_items.product_id

GROUP BY mnm_products.id
```

When i use only

```
SELECT name, stock,
SUM(shipping_items.qty) FROM shipping_items

JOIN mnm_products 
ON mnm_products.id = shipping_items.product_id
GROUP BY mnm_products.id
```

it´s right. But when i use 2 joins. the result of both are the same.
Can anybody help me there?

Comment: Your additional join is adding additional rows -- presumably one for each item.  This multiplies the number of rows being aggregated.  One solution is to pre-aggregate the results using the query that works.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: ok, can you give me an example? It should be grouped by the products ID

Comment: The standard way is to take the selected columns that are not arguments to set functions, and put those in the group by clause. In this case `GROUP BY name, stock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be best off with correlated subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select sum(si.qty)
        from shipping_items si
        where si.product_id = p.id
       ) as shipping_items,
       (select sum(oi.qty)
        from order_items oi
        where oi.product_id = p.id
       ) as order_items
from mnm_products p;
```

Comment: okay, thank you. And is it possible to add the items for a resuld? like SUM(order_items + shipping_items) as total

Comment: @WolfgangMüller . . . Probably the easiest way to do that is using a subquery.